# Generic mapping of return type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

Let's assume we have the following object:

```js
    interface X {
      a: () => number;
      b: number;
    }
```

And the following type:

```js
    type MethodsOf<T> = {
      [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never;
    }[keyof T];
```

The `MethodsOf` type will narrow only the keys of an object whose values are functions. For example:

```js
    type A = MethodsOf<X>; // "a"
    const a: A = 'a';
    const b: A = 'b'; // Error: Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
```

Now I am trying to create a generic type that will receive an `X` interface but will return a type whose keys are narrowed to `MethodsOf<X>` and its values are the types of the return values of the `MethodsOf<X>`. Example:

```js
    type ValuesMapping<T> = ???
    
    // No error:
    const mapping: ValuesMapping<X> = {
      a: 3
    }
    
    // Error:
    const mapping: ValuesMapping<X> = {
      a: 'blarg'
    }
```

I was trying to implement `type ValuesMapping<T>` as follows:

```js
    type ValuesMapping<T> = {
      [K in MethodsOf<T>]: ReturnType<T[K}>;
    };
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
    TS2344: Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.   Type 'T[MethodsOf<T>]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.     Type 'T[T[keyof T] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? keyof T : never]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.       Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.         Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.           Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
```

For some context of the issue, I am trying to create a generic mocking type:

```
type MethodsOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type MockMapping<T> = {
  [K in MethodsOf<T>]: Mock<ReturnType<T[K]>>;
};

// usage
class X {
  a() {
    return 1;
  }
  b = 2;
}

const x: MockMapping<X> = {
  a: jest.fn(() => 42),
};
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is unable to understand that the keys `K` of `T` calculated by `MethodsOf<T>` only point to valid function properties. The only thing TypeScript is sure is that `K` is actually a key of `T`. That's why indexing is still possible.

So we need to help TypeScript understand what the `T[K]` should be by using another conditional.

```
type ValuesMapping<T> = {
  [K in MethodsOf<T>]: 
    ReturnType<T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? T[K] : never>;
};
```

This compiles without an error.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4ChnLgLmQAoBKZAXgD5kQBXAWwCNoBuHZRwup1rAXyxYwATwAOKALIQwACwD2AEwDOAeRgAeACrVymdgG0A0slDIA1hGFyYyTQF1Cmo3eQQAHpBDLiAOj9woAHMlQjgQYX07Mio8cOQAfmRjLggAN14+fQsrG3s2ITEUAEEKZClZRVUNVEoWZAB6euQAIjhmrAQ5ECUwPEIS3Vbmtk7u3s5kAZbGYYamgFEoKDkoR0LkAHJmmY2TJRo5XrglJWBAkDhGABsUMDlkEXFNoY2fQQKngDU4K9oIJQkcFEolAgS0Oj0uCMJhAZWk8mUanBDmQACVpLQoCBNIUtM5XB4IF59kQ-D4AsFQuFItFqGFhAlbPiUukoLV+PksI1kAA5e7QZarDpdHrIehAkEgQIARkI31+-0BwNB6hqpWwuAIyAAzAAaDmCbmLQX4YVjMUS0EAJjlPz+AMtUtVEI1fWmVwpzX1fDYQA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So why do we need the `MethodsOf` type if we are telling TS that `T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any` ?

Comment: @vlio20 - you still only want the keys where `T[K]` is a function. If we would just map over `keyof T` we would end up with all properties of `T` where some would have a `never` type